# Form Control value becomes null OnSubmit when Disabled

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-reactive-forms

I have the following Angular 7 form:

```
ngOnInit() {

  this.organizationId = 1; // Used for testing

  this.form = this.formBuilder.group({     
    name: [''],
    organizationId: [{ value: this.organizationId, disabled: this.enableOrganizationChange }],
    start: ['']
  });

}
```

In the HTML I am using a `Select` for `OrganizationId`. It is disabled as expected.

However on submit the value is `null` and not 1:

```
onSubmit() {

  if (this.form.valid) {

    this.submitting = true;

    console.log(this.form.value.organizationId);

    let request: Request = { 
      name: this.form.value.name,
      organizationId: this.form.value.organizationId.value,
      start: this.form.value.start
    };

  }

}
```

Why is the logged value `null` and not `1`?

I am using disabled just to avoid the user to change the value.

But I still need the value on submit ...

Comment: `disabled` fields/input are not passed through `form.value`

Comment: Did you try `FormGroup.getRawValue`? 
 https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#getrawvalue

Answer (score 5):

As you noticed Angular ignores disabled form controls in the form object.

This can be easily fixed by using getRawValue(), which includes all form controls, disabled or not. So for example on your submit, you pass the form (NOT the form value) like so:

```
(ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form)" 
Then you can use getRawValue:

onSubmit() {
  console.log(form.getRawValue())
}
```

Note that all of this is happening using NgForms not ReactiveForms. 
You can change For ReactiveForms accordingly just by adding `getRawValue()` like: `console.log(this.form.organizationId.getRawValue());`

Comment: Not sure I get it but `console.log(this.form.organizationId.getRawValue())` gets undefined.

Comment: On my HTML form I have the `<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">`. Wouldn't this be the corrective way to use Reactive Forms? I would like to keep using Reactive Forms.

Comment: Well, if you want to stick with Reactive Forms  then check if its giving value of the disabled `Select` option by using: `console.log(this.form.controls.organizationId.getRawValue());` this is for FormGroup.

Comment: I think you mean `this.form.controls['organizationId'].value`

Comment: `.value` will not get disabled `select` option's value!

Comment: Are you sure? I tried and surprising it gets when using controls['organizationId']

Comment: If it works like this, thanks for increasing my knowledge then.

Comment: getRawValue() is the correct way to do this.  this.form.controls['organizationId'].value this is more like a hacking it.

Comment: @hunterTR I understand but by using form.getRawValue() I need to change the way I usually use Reactive forms, which is also as suggested in Angular site just because there is a disabled FormControl. Am I wrong? I update my OnSubmit to better explain. Maybe I am missing something from your answers.